# HTML CSS Button

Tags: html, css, button

I want to create the following button until tomorrow

[image: desired design]

I managed to create this with only css and html

[image: own html and css]

and here is my code.

```css
.date {
  color: #7ed2f6;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.save {
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.pill-button {
  border: 0.2em solid white;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

.right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  border: 0.3em solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}

.right:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 1.05em;
  margin-left: -0.6em;
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  border-top: 0.3em solid white;
  border-right: 0.3em solid white;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.greyline {
  border-left: 2px solid #8d9ab1;
  height: 81px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="pill-button">
  <span class="save">Save The Date</span>
  <div class="greyline"></div>
  <span class="date">Σάββατο 19/9/2020 16:30-17:30</span>
  <span class="right"></span>
</a>
```

I cant make it work with the line change

Comment: The problem is to make this button in my html

Comment: You need two additional spans inside the `date` span.

Comment: What spans? Can you please tell me?

Comment: Does @Gena Answer resolves your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I know this snippet doesn't have the same dimensions as yours but I think it should help you out.

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #1b2e52, #243f73);
  margin: 3em;
}

.pill-button {
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 1em;
  border: 0.125em solid white;
  color: white;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0.625em 4.375em 0.625em 1.25em;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3.75em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  width: 33.125em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.pill-button::before {
  content: "";
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 2.5em;
  border: 0.125em solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.375em;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.pill-button::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0.625em;
  height: 0.625em;
  border-top: 0.1875em solid white;
  border-right: 0.1875em solid white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1.5em;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.pill-button__save {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.875em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 7em;
}
.pill-button__save::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 0.0333333333em;
  height: 1.1666666667em;
  background-color: #8d9ab1;
}

.pill-button__date {
  color: #7ed2f6;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.pill-button__time-range {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="pill-button">
 <span class="pill-button__save">Save The Date</span>
 <span class="pill-button__date">Σάββατο 19/9/2020 <span class="pill-button__time-range">16:30-17:30</span></span>
</a>

<button class="pill-button">
 <span class="pill-button__save">Save The Date</span>
  <span class="pill-button__date">Σάββατο 19/9/2020 <span class="pill-button__time-range">16:30-17:30</span></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Hi, why isnt the a centered bt the button is? I need a center a

Answer (score 0):

The main idea to do this with flex. I did small refactoring.

```css
.date{
    color:#7ed2f6;
    font-size:40px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.save{
    color:white;
    font-size:40px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.pill-button {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 0.2em solid white; 
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  /* Added */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* End Added */
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 60px;
    
}

.right {
  /* display: inline-block; */
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  border: 0.3em solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}

.right:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 1.05em;
  margin-left: -0.6em;
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  border-top: 0.3em solid white;
  border-right: 0.3em solid white;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.greyline {
  border-left: 2px solid #8d9ab1;
  height: 81px;
  /* display: inline-block; */
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="pill-button">
 <span class="save">Save The Date</span>
 <div class="greyline"></div>
 <span class="date">Σάββατο 19/9/2020 16:30-17:30</span>
 <span class="right"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: Please, Run code snippet and see how button look, then switch to Full page view and You'll realize that Your solution doesn't resolve the problem.

Comment: What is the problem ? Describe and I will help

Comment: I left small fix, if you about content alignment

Comment: OP provide 2 pictures, 1st - desired button look and 2nd what he "get". When I `Run code snippet` Your button isn't what OP want, when I switch to `Full page` button isn't what OP want, again. If I understanf well, *Save The Date* must be in one line, and date and time need to be "divided" by new line. Or maybe I doesn't understand question well. I think he need to "play" little bit with fixed `width` of button, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.date{
    color:#7ed2f6;
    font-size:40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left:15px;
    margin-left:15px;
    border-left: 2px solid #8d9ab1;
    line-height:1;
}

.save{
    color:white;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight: bold;
      vertical-align:middle;
}

.pill-button {
    border: 0.2em solid white; 
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    width: max-content;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    background-color:#152b47;
}

.right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    border: 0.3em solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
}

.right:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 1.05em;
    margin-left: -0.6em;
    width: 1.2em;
    height: 1.2em;
    border-top: 0.3em solid white;
    border-right: 0.3em solid white;
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.greyline {
    border-left: 2px solid #8d9ab1;
    height: 81px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="pill-button">
    <span class="save">Save The Date</span>
      <div class="date">
        Σάββατο 19/9/2020<br>
        16:30-17:30
      </div>
    <span class="right"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your answer.I Think it works fine but I wanted the font size bigger so I made them 40 px but now the distance between the 2 lines Σαββατο 19/9/2020 and 16:30-17:30 is to big.How can I make the hight distance smaller?

Comment: @Stefanie I found a free webfont to match your original picture font if that can help you : https://webfonts.ffonts.net/Khand-Black.font.download Do you know how to use a custom webfont?

Comment: @Stefanie I have edited the answer to use the CSS line-height property. Adjust the line-height as needed. LaurentC has suggested a font. Do note that line-height varies with font. You may want to decide on the font and then adjust line-height as needed

Comment: Thanks again I dont know how to use web fonts but I have a question.Should this font size be adjusted when the screen gets smaller so it  always matches the picture and the lines never break?

Comment: That depends. I have a feeling you will have to adjust the font-size on mobile device. You can test it and see